# Format: KeyError when using curly brackets in strings

Tags: python, format

I'm running the following code:

```
asset = {}
asset['abc'] = 'def'
print type(asset)
print asset['abc']
query = '{"abc": "{abc}"}'.format(abc=asset['abc'])
print query
```

Which throws a `KeyError` error:

```
[user@localhost] : ~/Documents/vision/inputs/perma_sniff $ python ~/test.py 
<type 'dict'>
def
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    query = '\{"abc": "{abc}"\}'.format(abc=asset['abc'])
KeyError: '"abc"'
```

Format is obviously getting confused by the wrapping `{`. How can I make sure format only tries to replace the (correct) inner `{abc}`.

ie, expected output is:

```
{"abc": "def"}
```

(I'm aware I could use the `json` module for this task, but I want to avoid that. I would much rather use format.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To insert a literal brace, double it up:

```
query = '{{"abc": "{abc}"}}'.format(abc=asset['abc'])
```

(This is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), but not highlighted particularly obviously).

Answer (score 5):

wrap the outer braces in braces:

```
query = '{{"abc": "{abc}"}}'.format(abc=asset['abc'])
print query
{"abc": "def"}
```

Comment: think your double close brace is on the wrong one. should be: `'{{"abc": "{abc}"}}'`

Comment: @tom, yep, typo fixed

Answer (score 2):

The topmost curly braces are interpreted as a placeholder key inside your string, thus you get the `KeyError`. You need to escape them like this:

```
asset = {}
asset['abc'] = 'def'
query = '{{"abc": "{abc}"}}'.format(**asset)
```

And then:

```
>>> print query
{"abc": "def"}
```