# Why is Python interpreting this string as a dictionary when formatting?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am having problems using `format` with a string which looks like a Python dictionary.

I want to generate the following string: `{"one":1}`
If I try to do it as:

```
'{"one":{}}'.format(1)
```

the interpreter throws a KeyError:

```
>>> a = '{"one":{}}'.format(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '"one"'
```

I understand that the issue probably revolves around the fact that the string contains `{`, which can be confused with `format`'s `{}`. Why is this happening exactly and how can it be solved?

I know of percentage formatting, but I'd like to find a solution that doesn't involve ditching `format()`.

Comment: Keep in mind than percentage formatting is faster: format=0.7228269569986878, %=0.03355357599866693 ( result of `timeit.timeit`  on your example )

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Unless you're generating vast amounts of strings I don't think that really matters.

Comment: If you want to make a string of a dictionary, consider `str({"one":1})`.

Comment: Note: Even if the question isn't identical, if an answer explains the reason for something, [it still qualifies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983180/is-the-empty-tuple-in-python-a-constant#comment71144721_41983180).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ in this specific Q the issue isn't only how to solve this but why it is interpreted as a dictionary (which I address). Do you know any other answers that might answer the second part? If so please add it to the list of dupes. I'm leaning towards re-opening but I'm pretty sure there's an answer for the second issue too (Which I didn't find with a *very basic* search :-).

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard Found one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859757/format-keyerror-when-using-curly-brackets-in-strings

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Good enough for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The formatting of `'{"one": {}}'` is [using an identifier as the `field_name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#grammar-token-field_name) and will essentially try to look for a keyword argument that's been supplied to `.format` and has the name `'"one"'`.

As the docs state:

> The `field_name` itself begins with an `arg_name` that is either a number or a keyword. If it’s a number, it refers to a positional argument, and *if it’s a keyword, it refers to a named keyword argument.*

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

That's why you get the `KeyError` exception; it tries to look for a key in the mapping of keyword arguments provided to `format`. (which, in this case, is empty, hence the error).

As a solution, just escape the outer curly braces:

```
>>> '{{"one":{}}}'.format(1)
'{"one":1}'
```

The same remedy applies if you decide on using `f`-strings in the future:

```
>>> f'{{"one": {1}}}'
'{"one": 1}'
```

Comment: Ah! I knew escaping was the problem, but I was using `\` to escape, not double curly braces. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You need doubled curly braces `{{` `}}` to escape curly braces in string formatting.

```
a= '{{"one":{}}}'.format(1)
```

from [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include
>   a brace character in the literal text, **it can be escaped by doubling:
>   `{{` and `}}`**.

If you do not escape braces, `str.format()` will look for the value of key `'"one"'` to format the string. For example:

```
b = '{"one"} foo'.format(**{'"one"':1})
print(b) # 1 foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Braces can be escaped by using double braces, use:

```
'{{"one":{}}}'.format(1)
```